# IE11 javascript fails unless debugger is launched

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I hava  situation where some javascript a web page works fine in Safari and Chrome, but fails in IE11. Unfortunately due to issues with confidentiality I cannot put the javascript up here.

In IE11 the web page's java script fails to operate correctly. By that I mean some of the javascript works and some doesn't. With no errors displayed or any other indication of whats wrong.

If I try to debug the page using IE's developers tools, all the javascript works perfectly without any errors or issues.

Searching on the net I found many people with the same IE problem - fails normally, works when debugging. The main issues they talk about is the `console.log(...)` statement. I checked my javascript and don't have any `console.log(...)` statements.

I then saw a stackoverflow thread where adding a `cache:false` to the `$.ajax({...` calls solved the issue. I added the same flag but the problem still persists.

Are there any other bugs I've not found?

The web page is using jQuery to handle most of it's manipulation of the DOM with a single `$.ajax...` call and a series of `$.get(...` calls polling the server.

Comment: Sounds like a race condition issue

Comment: there are like bunch of other bugs and issues in IE that you could have hit ,, but if you do not share your code,, that's like we have to guess your issue,, that's not cool, don't you think?

Comment: `due to issues with confidentiality I cannot put the javascript up here` - what you'll need to do is spend some time to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the same issue but does not breach confidentiality. Of course, by spending the time creating such an example, you'll probably find the issue yourself, ironically, and wont need any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to debug your web pages.....IE11 tips.

All modern web browsers suppress scripting error messages and warnings by default. (In the early days web browsers would halt page loading/rendering and display a script error message with an alert statement)... this gives the best user experience who isn't concerned with the internal workings of web site code.

So, scripting errors will only BREAK execution if:
1. The browser debug tool is opened. and
2. The developer tools' Debug tab setting for Break on Exceptions has been turned on.

So to debug your web pages.
1. navigate to about:blank to start a testing cycle.....press f11 to display the dev tool, select "Break on all exceptions" from the dropdown (looks like a stop sign). Pin the dev tool to the bottom of the browser.
2. Return to the browser address bar and navigate to your test site (typed address of paste and go)...

The dev tool will now break on ALL exceptions and you will list them in the console tab.

IE has built-in content blocking and has ActiveX filtering (ad blocking) which can affect outcomes. You need to configure Internet Options so that the IE dev tool console will record any blocked content or security (XSS) errors.

Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages".

Also on the Emulation tab of the IE dev tool you will find the Emulation Mode (aka documentMode) that IE is using, and how it was established eg. x-ua meta, Enterprise site mode list, user Compatibility View list, etc

If you are developing an internal company website, the emulation mode used by IE may be for an earlier version of IE.. (IE8 on XP).. you should include this information with your questions.

You should also include the IE security zone that your site has been mapped to.. File>Properties menu in IE.... eg. Intranet zone as this can have different security and blocked content outcomes.

finally, the first step in troubleshooting web browser issues is to test in noAddons mode (for IE, winkey+r>iexplore.exe -extoff ). IE has built-in form-fillers and popup blockers... third-party addons can affect the outcomes expected.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this. I'll give it a try. Although admittedly, I've since told the users to stop using IE as they are quite happy with Chrome and Safari. :-)